# How Count Absences time in php

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, counting

i want to get the absences Hours of each student .

> Exemple :

```
$student_absence_from_time = 08:00 -> $student_absence_to_time = 10:00 
$student_absence_from_time = 09:00 -> $student_absence_to_time = 10:00 
$student_absence_from_time = 08:00 -> $student_absence_to_time = 09:00`
```

i want to get the diffrence between `$student_absence_from_time` and `$student_absence_to_time` and count the diffrence to get total absence time of each student like this 10:00 - 08:00 = 2 hour + 10:00 - 08:00 = 2h + 09:00 - 08:00 = 1 hour total absence time is 5 Hours
thanks you :)

Comment: Check out Datetime with something like `$datetimeFrom->diff($datetimeTo);`

Comment: and what's the issue?

Comment: This is pretty basic programming to be honest. I'd suggest breaking the problem down and trying to research how to do each step you don't understand.

Comment: i just want to how count the total of absences hours of each student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert the time and then [array-reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to count them.

Consider the following:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = array("student_absence_from_time" => "08:00", "student_absence_to_time" => "10:00");
$arr[] = array("student_absence_from_time" => "09:00", "student_absence_to_time" => "10:00");
$arr[] = array("student_absence_from_time" => "08:00", "student_absence_to_time" => "09:00");

function cntAbsence($carry, $item) {
    return $carry +  strtotime($item["student_absence_to_time"]) - strtotime($item["student_absence_from_time"]);
} // adding the different between "from_time" to "to_time"
echo array_reduce($arr, "cntAbsence", 0) / 3600; // time is in second so divided by 3600 to get hours and use 0 as init
```

Comment: thank you very much it's work correctly just remove $arr = array();

Answer (score 0):

Get and store timestamp as result of function `time()` (seconds since 1970) and not as text. This time is independent of any timezone. A difference between 2 timestamps is the number of gone seconds. Use `date()` or `strftime()` (I prefer second) to print timestamps as text.

btw, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is the SQL equivalent of `time()`.